# Processing delimiters with python

Tags: python, regex, logging, extract

Im currently trying to parse a apache log in a format I can't do normally. (Tried using goaccess)

In sublime it the delimiters show up as ENQ, SOH, and ETX which too my understanding are "|", space, and superscript L.  Im trying to use re.split to separate the individual components of the log, but i'm not sure how to deal w/ the superscript L.

On sublime it shows up as `3286d68255beaf010000543a000012f1/Madonna_Home_1.jpgENQx628a135bENQZ1e5ENQAB50632SOHA50.134.214.130SOHC98.138.19.91SOHD42857ENQwwww.newprophecy.net...`

With ENQ's as '|' and SOH as ' ' when I open the file in a plain text editor (Like notepad)

I just need to parse out the IP addresses so the rest of the line is mostly irrelevant.

Currently I have

```
pkts = re.split("\s|\\|")
```

But I don't know what to do for the L.

Comment: An example along with expected ouptut would be better.

Comment: What's wrong with copy and pasting subscript L in regex?

Comment: Please give some example, like sample Input and sample output.

Comment: Most web servers use the [common log format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Log_Format) by default. But they generally also allow you to change it. If you can do so, choose a log format where you use a normally unused character as a field seperator. Then you can do a simple `split()` to get the different fields.

Comment: @AvinashRaj added an example, and I can't copy and paste the L since it defaults to a question mark (Although that might be the actual character I'm not sure)

Answer (score 0):

Those 3-letter codes are ASCII control codes - these are ASCII characters which occur prior to 32 (space character) in the ASCII character set. You can find [a full list online](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/c0.html).

These character do not correspond to anything printable, so you're incorrect in assuming they correspond to those characters. You can refer to them as literals in several languages using `\x00` notation - for example, control code ETX corresponds to `\x03` (see the reference I linked to above). You can use these to split strings or anything else.

This is the literal answer to your question, but all this aside I find it quite unlikely that you *actually* need to split your Apache log file by control codes. At a guess what's actually happened is that perhaps som Unicode characters have crept into your log file somehow, perhaps with UTF-8 encoding. An encoding is a way of representing characters that extend beyond the 255 limit of a single byte by encoding extended characters with multiple bytes.

There are several types of encoding, but UTF-8 is one of the most popular. If you use UTF-8 it has the property that standard ASCII characters will appear as normal (so you might never even realise that UTF-8 was being used), but if you view the file in an editor which isn't UTF-8 aware (or which incorrectly identifies the file as plain ASCII) then you'll see these odd control codes. These are places where really the code and the character(s) before or after it should be interpreted together as a single unit.

I'm not sure that this is the reason, it's just an educated guess, but if you haven't already considered it then it's important to figure out the encoding of your file since it'll affect how you interpret the entire content of it. I suggest loading the file into an editor that understands encodings (I'm sure something as popular as Sublime does with proper configuration) and force the encoding to UTF-8 and see if that makes the content seem more sensible.

Comment: So is there anyway to process them as strings? When I try to readline in python it gives e the error "codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90"  Which means the encoding's not specified, but I have earlier when I opened the file so I'm at a lost for what to do.

Comment: `0x90` sounds like a UTF-8 continuation byte to me. That error means that a charmap encoding is used, I think - which source file does the error come from? `cp1252.py` is a common culprit on Windows, for example. The source file will probably tell you which encoding is in use. If you want to try UTF-8 then open the file like this: `fd = open(filename, encoding="utf8")`

Comment: (If you're using Python 2 use [`codecs.open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open) instead).

Comment: I got the file to read (issue with another function), however I still can't seem to split the string properly. Here is a link a picture of an example string http://i.imgur.com/11KZfDS.png (can't post pictures not enough rep) I'm not sure how I would split it at this point.

Comment: It doesn't look to me like those characters are what you want to split on - I think if you read the file with the correct encoding then you probably wouldn't get those chars at all, and my personal suspicion is that's the better solution for you. If you just split the raw string I think you'll have other issues, such as confusion between delimiters and content. However, if you really do want to just split on, say, ENQ then try `my_string.split('\x05')` - does that work for you? You can find the other codes using the list I linked to in my answer.